# X and Y axis rotation only working as Z axis rotation

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

When I try rotation x(red) axis rotation or y(green)axis rotation, it always uses z(blue) axis rotation.
i.e. instead of it rotation down it rotates left and right instead. Is this a bug or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: I have never seen a bug like this myself. Does this happen on all blender files or just one? Can you test in a new project? Also, a picture or video of the phenomenon would help.

Comment: as person132 says we lack informations, please show some screenshots, perhaps you've simply locked the rotation of the object on its X and Y axis?